# Tensorflow: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options' in Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, ubuntu-16.04, object-detection-api

I tried installing Tensorflow object detection API from this guide:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

I have installed all the dependencies and when I try to test the run the .py file it throws the "got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options' " as mentioned in the title.

As mentioned by most of the people regarding the downgrading of protobuf protoc version to 3.4, I have tried doing that and my version is 3.4, but still it throws the same error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Update `protobuf` to last version (3.6.x currently).

Please refer to this github issue-comment if you want know more: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4716#issuecomment-428293527

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. upgrade to Protobuf 3.6.0 or
2. hand delete the "serialized_options=None," argument from the generated `*_pb2.py` files.